# MonoDevelop: Semi cryptic error CS0016

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, anonymous-types

Here's the error I'm getting:

Error CS0016: Could not write to file `Fact.Apprentice.Core', cause: Type '<>__AnonType0`2' was not completed. (CS0016) (Fact.Apprentice.Core - Mono)

If I compile using MonoDevelop + Microsoft .NET, no such error shows up.  When using Mono framework, I am unable to compile because of this.  Behavior identical for Mac or PC installation.

Comment: please help us help you :-) Edit your question to be more specific, e.g. give us the code that provoke this error, the Mono version number and compiler used (e.g. gmcs 2.8)...

Comment: That's the thing about it, there is no clue as to what code is causing this error.  Usually it takes me to the offending code, but not this time.  It merely points to my project file, which contains about 3 dozen .CS files.  As for versions, I'm using MonoDevelop 2.8.1 w/ Mono 2.10.6.  Where might I find the gmcs version?

Comment: "Could not write to file", do you have a virus scanner? McAfee does similar to me with python and very occasionally vstudio.

Comment: On the Mac there's no virus scanner.  And other projects compile OK

Comment: Nobody can help on this? Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error usually indicates compiler bug. The most likely source will be some of your LINQ queries. You could also try Mono 2.11 which should give you better error message.